# Looping through table rows where the table's class attr contains class1 or class2

Tags: jquery

I need to loop though a table where the table rows contain either class1 or class2 , how to I go about doing this.

Tried the following, but not working

```
var trs = $("#emailTable tr");

trs.each(function(i,n){
    var current = $(n+":has(.class1 .class2)").attr('class');
    alert(current)
});
```

Comment: jQuery is a good start. I'd then look at the jQuery documentation and go on from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using the folllowing code:

```
$("#emailTable tr.class1, #emailTable tr.class2").each(function (ix, element) {
    // Do your processing.
});
```

Comment: This is correct, however you are missing the closing `);` at the end of the each.

Answer (score 1):

Simply enter a comma between the two classes in your selector.

$(".a, .b")

this will match all elements with class "a" OR class "b"

You should add logic to the selector so that it only takes the rows of the table you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
$('#table tr.class1,#table tr.class2').each(function(i, elem) {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector would be `$(".class1,.class2")` .